# specific distance (white space) between columns of drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net

Before I had a question about (specific distance (space) between columns of drop down list) and I received my answer like below code, my problem is the spaces between columns will be fill by '_', when I change that to something like " ", it does not work and columns are beside each other, I need white space between columns, how can I do that?

```
protected void ddlStack_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var all = from o in _DataContext.tblDocuments
              orderby o.DocumentNo
              select o;
    int maxs = 0;
    foreach (tblDocuments v in all)
    {
        if (v.DocumentNo.Length > maxs)
            maxs = v.DocumentNo.Length;
    }

    foreach (tblDocuments vv in all)
    {
        string doctitle = vv.DocumentNo;
        for (int i = vv.DocumentNo.Length; i < maxs + 2; i++)
        {
            doctitle += '_';
        }
        doctitle += " | ";
        doctitle +=  vv.DocID;
        ddlStack.Items.Add(new ListItem(doctitle, vv.vendorID.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **`&nbsp;`** instead of a regular " " (space) and then use **HtmlDecode** before creating the ListBoxItem...

Try something like this:

```
foreach (tblDocuments vv in all)
{
    string doctitle = vv.DocumentNo;
    for (int i = vv.DocumentNo.Length; i < maxs + 2; i++)
    {
        doctitle += "&nbsp;";

    }
    doctitle += "&nbsp;|&nbsp;";
    doctitle +=  vv.DocID;

    // Use HtmlDecode to correctly show the spaces
    doctitle = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(doctitle );

    ddlStack.Items.Add(new ListItem(doctitle, vv.vendorID.ToString()));
}
```